# Getting 500 error when submitting a faceboot FB.ui share using share_open_graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I've got a quiz on my website and I want users to share it to facebook afterwards. It needs to share their score so it can't be a standard share with opengraph meta tags - hence it needs to use the FB.ui bit.

The code works in that it brings up the share popup with all the correct data in the right places. But when you click on "Post" it hangs. Digging into the developer tools it looks like Facebook has responded with an error 500.

```
$(".wpProQuiz_facebook_button").click(function(){

//generics pulled from Quiz
var marks = $(".wpProQuiz_correct_answer").text();
var total = $(".wpProQuiz_total").text();
var quiz_url = window.location.href;

//quiz title (custom for each quiz)
var facebook_quiz_descr = $("#facebook_quiz_descr").text();
//share image url (custom for each quiz)
var facebook_share_image_url = $("#facebook_share_image").attr("src");

FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object : {
          'og:url': quiz_url,
          'og:title': 'I got '+marks+' out of '+total+'! What will you get?',
          'og:description': facebook_quiz_descr,
          'og:image:url': facebook_share_image_url,
          'og:image:width': '1200',
          'og:image:height': '630'
        }
    })
  });
});
```

ANy ideas what's gone wrong? The header's got the appid in and like I say, it creates the share popup absolutely fine. I'm completely stumped and have wasted so much time already!

TIA

Comment: If you get a 500 from Facebook, file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs (If it was a mistake on your end, wrong parameters, something missing or whatever - then the API should at least tell you a reason.)

Comment: Thanks. It was confirmed as a bug that they're investigating. In the end I solved my problem with a workaround that added parameters to a resulting url. When Facebook queried that url, it would it would give the correct title by manipulating meta og tags via PHP.